# How to make the source directory visible in Eclipse M2T JET projects?

Tags: eclipse, package-explorer, eclipse-m2t-jet

I just started to play around with [Eclipse M2T JET2](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/m2t/?project=jet#jet). Now I noticed that the jet2java directory, containing the generated Java sources, is hidden in my workspace. Also, when I create a src directory, it is hidden...

Now I was wondering whether there is a trick to make the source directories visible again in JET2 project, so it is easier to see what java code is generated from my templates and to add some additional (glue) code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it out, just follow these steps:

1. In the Package Explorer click on the little white down-pointing triangle.
2. Click Filters... in the menu
3. Find 'Java elements from JET Transformation project' and deselect it

Now the generated JET code directory is visible

*Hint*: Lots of other Package Explorer filters can be (un)applied using these steps!